# Merging 4 observable with conditions

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to create an Observable that will collect other observables coming from some http requests. The new observable must be a collection of same object type but every item must be unique. Can you help me writing the correct method to achieve this goal?

```js
// The result observable that I need
topicCollection$ = BehaviorSubject<Topic[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Topic[]>(null);

// Boolean observable of authentication
isAuthenticated: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);

// Return default topic
get defaultTopics$(): Observable<Topic[]>{
   return this.defaultTopic.asObservable();
}

// Return topics selected by Admin
get TopTopics$(): Observable<Topic[]>{
  return this.topTopic.asObservable();
}

//Return topics selected by User
get userTopics$: Observable<Topic[]>{
   return this.userTopic.asObservable();
}

//Return user settings 
get userSettings$(): Observable<any[]>{
  return this.userSettings.asObservable();
}
```

So the constraint are:

1. If user is not logged collection must be in this order: defaultTopic, topTopic
2. If user is logged collection must be in this order:defaultTopic, topTopic, userTopic
3. If user is logged I will read the UserSettings$ that filter the defaultTopics if they will be hidden or shown
4. Topic must be unique (duplicate topics would be only in default and user topic observable)

I try with combineLatest and forkJoin but I don't know how to differenziate the operators with the authentication observer.

Comment: try using forkjoin?

Comment: Is there a reason everything's a `BehaviourSubject`? Is there a semantics to the default `null` case? Null isn't 'a collection of same object type' - so I'm not sure what you want is possible given your current setup. How do you know if a user is logged in? Is that part of user settings? `userSettings` can be a list of anything, how should a filter on a list of anything work? `defaultTopic`, `topTopic`, and `userTopic` are all lists, when you say order what do you mean? Concatenating them? If you find duplicates, how do you preserve your order while removing them (which one is removed)?

Comment: I used BehaviourSubject because I want the last value, null because I made a mistake writing :)
I know if a user is logged in if isAuthenticated emits true.
UserSettings is a list of {key: value}, for example {topicOfTheDay: 'off'} so if the label of Topic == 'topicOfTheDay' and is off I want to hide this.
For the orders I mean Concatenating them
If I find duplicates I want to remove the userTopic one.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Of course since your question isn't complete, neither is this answer.

You'll have to implement a few parts yourself. Still, the following should be a decent place to start tinkering.

```ts
get topicCollection$(): Observable<Topic[]> {

  return this.isAuthenticated.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(isLogged => {

      // The easy part, merge arrays emitted from two separate streams
      const mergeDefaultTop$ = forkJoin([
        this.defaultTopics$.pipe(take(1)),
        this.topTopics$.pipe(take(1))
      ]).pipe(
        map((v: Topic[][]) => v.flat())
      );

      // If the user is logged in, merge then filter the merged topics.
      return !isLogged ? mergeDefaultTop$ : mergeDefaultTop$.pipe(
        switchMap(topics => this.userTopics$.pipe(
          map(userTopics => [...topics, ...userTopics])
        )),
        switchMap(topics => this.userSettings$.pipe(
          map(settings => topics
            // You'll want to update this filter. I can't define it for you 
            // as I dont know what a topic is/ how it's labled, etc.
            .filter(topic => topic !in settings)
            // Filter to remove duplicats. You may want to better define
            // equality depending on your use case (again, I can't do
            // that for you with what you've provided)
            .filter((value, index, self) =>
              self.indexOf(value) === index
            )
          )
        ))
      );

    })
  );

}
```